# Protocol buffers - unique numbered tag - clarification?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I'm using protocol buffers  and everything is working fine. except that the fact that I don't understand  - why do I need the numbered tags in the `proto` file :

```
message SearchRequest {
  required string query = 1;
  optional int32 page_number = 2;
  optional int32 result_per_page = 3;
}
```

Sure I've read the [**docs**](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto) :

> As you can see, each field in the message definition has a unique
>   numbered tag. These tags are used to identify your fields in the
>   message binary format, and should not be changed once your message
>   type is in use.

I didn't understand what difference does it make if I change it . ( I will create a new proto and compile it  - so why does it care ?)

[Another article states that :](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2014/06/05/choose-protocol-buffers/)

> Numbered fields in proto definitions obviate the need for version
>   checks which is one of the explicitly stated motivations for the
>   design and implementation of Protocol Buffers. As the developer
>   documentation states, the protocol was designed in part to avoid “ugly
>   code” like this for checking protocol versions:

```
if (version == 3) {
  ...
} else if (version > 4) {
  if (version == 5) {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

**Question**

Is it just me or it is completely unclear ?

let me ask it in a different way :

If I have a proto file like the above file , and then I change it to :

```
message SearchRequest {
  required string query = 3; //reversed order
  optional int32 page_number = 2;
  optional int32 result_per_page = 1;
}
```

What does it care ? I re-compile and add the file ( i've done it multiple times in the last week).

what am I missing ? can you please supply a human-to human explanation  for this numbered tags ?

Comment: `What does it care` In my opinion, you're making a great point here. If you don't really need the backwards compatability then it feels very pointless to have to explicitly declare the numbers. They could (and for my small, internal project, should) be automatically generated.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The numbered tags are used to match fields when serializing and deserializing the data.

Obviously, if you change the numbering scheme, and apply this change to both serializer and deserializer, there is no issue.

Consider though, if you saved data with the first numbering scheme, and loaded it with the second one, it would try to load `query` into `result_per_page`, and deserialization would likely fail.

Now, why is this useful?
Let's say you need to add another field to your data, long after the schema is already in use:

```
message SearchRequest {
  required string query = 1;
  optional int32 page_number = 2;
  optional int32 result_per_page = 3;
  optional int32 new_data = 4;
}
```

Because you explicitly give it a number, your deserializer is still able to load data serialized with the *old* numbering scheme, ignoring deserialization of non-existent data.

Comment: Now it's understood.  was it so hard for them to example it ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir it is very well explained https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding. See sample as my post below

Comment: @almasshaikh  In a situation where a brief ( 15 lines!) does not explains it simply enough in a briefly way - which forces me to go to internals ---well I find that disturbing.

Comment: @RoyiNamir This thinking varies from person to person i think. It's always to be verbose rather than brief so you never get counter questions or leave reader with confusions. So nvm ;)

Comment: @RoyiNamir Sorry if our docs weren't clear enough. FWIW, this topic is also covered in the [language guide](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#simple) (under "Assigning Tags").

Comment: It feels very silly to have to add the tags. I get why the tags are there, but it shouldn't  be mandatory to manually set them imo.

Comment: @Birger How so? What solution would you use instead to identify the fields?

Comment: I'm just saying I'd rather not have to explicitly, manually set numbers on the tags. For instance in a project of mine I have full control of both ends of the messaging system. If the .proto files are modified I'm updating both ends accordingly, so the protocol buffers compiler could automatically generate the tag numbers for the code and it wouldn't ever be a problem with number mismatches. Then I feel it's a waste of time having to manually add tag numbers. Just to be clear you're answer is as good as any, I'm just ventilating some dissatisfaction here ;-)

Comment: @Rotem, but this new field is optional, so it should be deserialized anyway if it was provided or not. In case of new required field then it will not deserialize the message with the old schema anyway, so I still don't understand...

Comment: @BorisMitioglov How will it know which field is which? If you get a packet with a `string` and two `int32`s, which fields on the objects do you populate?

Comment: @Rotem, looks like I understood, the key is that it's a binary format so those numbers are like offsets for our fields, so even if we have optional field in a message we should still know where it is located in binary format to deserialize the message, am I right?

Comment: @BorisMitioglov The field numbers don't represent byte offsets if that's what you mean, they are just arbitrary identifiers, but everything else you wrote is correct. In a binary format you need some system for knowing what each piece of data represents, unlike e.g. JSON where the name of the field is serialized in the message.

Comment: @Rotem why isn't the implied ordinality sufficient? Perhaps an example with a removed field could clarify things?

Answer (score 5):

These field numbers are used by protobuf while encoding and decoding. See [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding) for more details.

So each and every field has wire type so int32 has wire type as 0 and your field number say is 2 so it will be encoded as 0001 0000 i.e. 10 in hex.

And later on when its decoded, its left shifted by 1 which makes it as 001 0000 and last three lsb decides wire type i.e. it then makes out its of type int field and rest decides which field in proto it is i.e. 00010 is 2. So field 2 of wire type 0 (int)