# Safeness of changing proto field number

Tags: protocol-buffers

For example if I changed from:

```
message Request {
  int foo = 1;
}
```

to

```
message Request {
  int bar = 1;
  int foo = 2;
}
```

Is it safe to change `foo` from 1 to 2? [Docs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#assigning_field_numbers) say not to: `These numbers are used to identify your fields in the message binary format, and should not be changed once your message type is in use.`, but I'd like to know why.

Comment: We follow this convention for online service too and we use the reserved keywords anytime (two time in three years) a field is removed from the message

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I change the numbered tags in a proto file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66642064/can-i-change-the-numbered-tags-in-a-proto-file)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a serialized version of the message generated with the first version, you will no be able to deserialize with the second version of the message.
If you use protobuf to generate a model to store in a DB or to be published in a broker like Apache Kafka,  you need to follow the convention. If you use proto buffer to generate model and service for online usage, you should do not break anything (if you will regenerate all the models)

See also the [reserved keyword](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#reserved) in order to do not reuse an old numer. Further reading also [here](https://john-millikin.com/effective-grpc#tombstones)

Comment: Let's say I had a Library A owning the protos, and Library B using the protos such as `myRequest.foo`. If I changed the field number of `foo` in Library A, will Library B break if it tries to process the new proto with the old code?

Comment: @onepiece it shouldn't break (meaning: throw a fault) unless the old code knew about some other field 2 with a different type (which is why removing fields is dangerous if you don't mark them as reserved). However, newly serialized uses field 1 for bar and 2 for foo; the old serializer code will therefore deserialize what *was* the bar values, into the field named foo, and what was the foo value will be lost (or stored in a harder-to-access API as unknown field data). Only the field number (not name) is stored on the wire. Basically, **don't change field numbers**. Pretty much ever.

Comment: @MarcGravell Is it fine to change field numbers if say the proto is owned and only used in Library A? Then all usages of the proto will be updated together. I also saw https://stackoverflow.com/a/26826460/1661745 - `if you change the numbering scheme, and apply this change to both serializer and deserializer, there is no issue.`

Comment: @onepiece that depends: do you have any payloads stored in files? In databases? In message queues? If the answer to any of these (and more) is "possibly", then **no it isn't OK**. Frankly, you gain absolutely nothing by changing the field number, and risk a lot. To me, that's a lot of words and wasted time that can saved by simply *leaving the field alone*. No-one will mind.