# Can I change the numbered tags in a proto file?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26826421/protocol-buffers-unique-numbered-tag-clarification) describes what the numbered tags in proto files are for, essentially match fields when serializing and deserializing the data. My question is: *what happens if I change the number of an existing field?*

Taking the same example, say this is the original data

```
message SearchRequest {
  required string query = 1;
  // Pagination fields
  optional int32 page_number = 2;
  optional int32 result_per_page = 3;
}
```

And I want to add a new field, which logically makes sense to put before the pagination fields -  Can I re-enumerate the fields as below, if I'm not using the `page_number` and `result_per_page` fields yet (though the message type `SearchRequest` is in use)?

```
message SearchRequest {
  required string query = 1;
  optional int32 new_data = 2;
  // Pagination fields
  optional int32 page_number = 3;
  optional int32 result_per_page = 4;
}
```

Should I have given the pagination fields higher numbers from the start to allow for new fields?

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#assigning_field_numbers) says

> These field numbers are used to identify your fields in the message
> binary format, and should not be changed once your message type is in
> use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing field numbers is almost always a bad idea - you will get very odd behaviour unless all clients and servers are.deployed at exactly the same time and there is no persisted payload data anywhere (in files, databases, etc). In particular, the serializer will try to interpret data as a different thing: in some cases this will cause a serialization failure and in other cases it will silently and happily deserialize the data *with garbage meaning*, causing chaos.

There is no reason not to simply use field 5.

Comment: Thanks! Is it best to add them numerical order or group them as they fit logically? I understand adding them logically can make it hard to find the next available number if there are a lot of fields. On the other hand, my IDE tells me if I have a duplicate so it shouldn't be that hard to find the next number to use.

Comment: @Toni "best" is subjective; do whatever works for you; personally I'd add them in numerical order, but...